# Probe Interaction with multiple imputed Data

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, analysis, r-mice

I would like to probe an interaction in a **moderation analysis** between a **categorical predictor** and a **continuous variable** in a **multiple imputed** data set.
I would like to look at the effect of different levels of the continuous moderator (-1SD, Mean, +1SD).

I know that this is possible in SPSS with the `PROCESS` macro, but unfortunately, it cannot handle multiple imputed data. The `interaction` package can't handle it either. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

I have imputed the data with the `mice` package, with m = 50.

My model looks like this:

```
lm(outcome ~ group * continuous_moderator)
```

Here is a reproducible example, using the windspeed dataset integrated in mice:

```
data <- mice::windspeed
data$group <- sample(c(0:1), replace = T, size = 433)

imp_data <- mice(data,
                 m=50,
                 maxit=20,
                 meth='cart',
                 seed=12345)

model1 <- with(imp_data,
               lm(RochePt ~ group * Clones))
```

Thanks in advance for all your help and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [the `marginaleffects` package.] (Disclaimer: I am the author.) See this vignette for details:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/multiple_imputation.html

The quick illustration below uses the `by` argument which is available in the dev version (should be out on CRAN in the next couple weeks). Install it:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")
```

Then,

```r
library(mice)
library(marginaleffects)

data <- mice::windspeed

# {marginaleffects} reserves the name "group", so I "group_id" instead
data$group_id <- sample(c(0:1), replace = T, size = 433)

fit <- function(x) {
    mod <- lm(RochePt ~ group_id * Clones, data = x)
    out <- comparisons(mod, variables = "Clones", by = "group_id")
    # see vignette linked above for why we need the next line.
    out$term <- out$group_id
    return(out)
}

imp_data <- mice(data,
    m = 5,
    maxit = 20,
    meth = "cart",
    seed = 12345,
    printFlag = FALSE)
imp_data <- complete(imp_data, "all")

mod <- lapply(imp_data, fit)

mice::pool(mod)
#> Class: mipo    m = 5 
#>   term m  estimate        ubar b           t dfcom       df riv lambda
#> 1    1 5 0.9394599 0.002593162 0 0.002593162   433 430.9702   0      0
#> 2    0 5 1.0443336 0.003134239 0 0.003134239   433 430.9702   0      0
#>           fmi
#> 1 0.004608611
#> 2 0.004608611
```

Edit: Here’s a minimal example using the `newdata` argument and the `datagrid()` function to assess contrasts conditional on a continuous moderator. You can then modify the `fit` function I gave you before to integrate this in your multiple imputation workflow.

Please read the documentation to learn more. It is very detailed and the functions are super flexible: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/

```r
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = "cyl",
    newdata = datagrid(hp = c(100, 110, 120)))
#>   rowid     type        term contrast_cyl comparison std.error
#> 1     1 response interaction        6 - 4  -4.792913  2.016159
#> 2     2 response interaction        6 - 4  -3.741286  2.025602
#> 3     3 response interaction        6 - 4  -2.689660  2.253712
#> 4     1 response interaction        8 - 4  -8.049775  2.314779
#> 5     2 response interaction        8 - 4  -7.064458  2.393402
#> 6     3 response interaction        8 - 4  -6.079140  2.563475
#>   statistic      p.value   conf.low  conf.high predicted_lo
#> 1 -2.377250 0.0174422739  -8.744511 -0.8413143     24.70544
#> 2 -1.847000 0.0647471270  -7.711393  0.2288198     23.57768
#> 3 -1.193436 0.2326988568  -7.106855  1.7275346     22.44992
#> 4 -3.477557 0.0005060048 -12.586658 -3.5128926     24.70544
#> 5 -2.951639 0.0031609267 -11.755439 -2.3734759     23.57768
#> 6 -2.371445 0.0177186636 -11.103458 -1.0548222     22.44992
#>   predicted_hi cyl  hp
#> 1     19.91252   8 100
#> 2     19.83639   8 110
#> 3     19.76026   8 120
#> 4     16.65566   8 100
#> 5     16.51322   8 110
#> 6     16.37078   8 120
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and helpful comment. 
This looks very promising. I would just like to examine my **continuous moderator** (in this example `clones`) for different levels and *not* the categorical predictor (in this case `group`). The `probe_interaction()` function from the `interaction` package does this automatically, dividing the continuous moderator into **mean, +1 SD and -1SD**. Is this also possible in your package? I am not sure if I get the same results if I convert the moderator into a three-level factor beforehand.

Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: Yes, that's very easy. I edited my answer with a second example with a continuous moderator.